# Count all occurrences of reference, ignoring visual and dividing equally

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've come across another fuzzy scenario and I'm wondering if anyone may be able to help.

I have three tables

**Invoices**

| *Invoice Ref* | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Inv1 | 10,000 |
| Inv2 | 9,999 |

**Invoice Categories**

| *Invoice Ref* | *Category* |
| --- | --- |
| Inv1 | 1 |
| Inv2 | 2 |
| Inv2 | 2 |

**Categories**

| *Category Ref* | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Stuff |
| 2 | Things |

They join to create a situation where an invoice can have multiple categories.

I have a PowerBI visual that displays like this

| Invoice Ref | Count | Value | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Inv1 | 1 | 10,000 | Stuff |
| Inv1 | 1 | 10,000 | Things |
| Inv2 | 1 | 9,999 | Things |

However, I need it to be (counting the total rows of the reference and dividing equally between the two)

| Invoice Ref | Count | Value | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Inv1 | 2 | 5,000 | Stuff |
| Inv1 | 2 | 5,000 | Things |
| Inv2 | 1 | 9,999 | Things |

Sorry for the table spam. I can't find a decent way to articulate it. Also, what is this operation called so I can do some reading?

Comment: I'm attempting to resolve this using ALL / ALL EXCEPT but I seem to be missing some understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels wrong or dirty - anyways try the following Measures:

```
Category count = 
  var meCount = COUNTROWS('Invoice Categories')
  var allCount = 
    CALCULATE(
      COUNTROWS('Invoice Categories'),
      ALLSELECTED('Categories')
    )
  return IF(NOT ISBLANK(meCount), allCount)


Invoice Category amount = 
  var s = SUM(Invoices[Value])
  return
    IF(
      ISINSCOPE('Categories'[Description]),
      DIVIDE(s, [Category count]),
      s
    )
```

[image]

Comment: I don't disagree in the slightest that it's both wrong and dirty. But your solution seems to work as it needs to. Also gives me some functions to read into! If there's a better way, very open to it. But thanks!